# Call a Javascript function from a vb.net class

Tags: javascript, vb.net

My web application which has 2 tiers. UI tier where the pages and javascript files reside. Business Layer tier with all the .net classes to save the data. In my Javascript file, i have a long function which takes an Object as a parameter and converts it onto a xml string. something like this:

```
function objToXML(obj) {
    var strXML = '<Data>';
    strXML = strXML + '<Name>' + obj.Name + '</Name>'
    strXML = strXML + '</Data>'
    return strXML;
}
```

In my business layer class, i need the same feature of converting the .net class to xml. But i do not want to write the long method in vb.net again as it has 100+ properties (above was just a sample).

is there any way by which i can use the same Jaavscript function on the server side business layer, where i do not have any acccess to the page.

Thanks.

Comment: No, since javascript is run on the client and the server does not have access to the client :( you could use the built-in .net feature to serialize your object to xml, instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: the xm is a custom built xml as per some business logic. so cannot use inbuilt xml serializer.

Comment: Have you tried using DataContract? Since I don't know the business logic, this might not work in your case.